# Export Raster Data to TIFF, BMP, or PNG File using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, export

I am writing a Python script to export a Raster Dataset to a TIFF, BMP, or PNG file, as I would manually by right-clicking on the layer, choosing Data | Export Data, and then make my choices in the Export Raster Data window.  Can this be duplicated with ArcPy, and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another solution would be to use the [Copy Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000) tool:

```
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(in_raster, out_rasterdataset)
```

Where you add the file extension  to `out_rasterdataset`

Comment: I was just writing this answer. I like this tool better than 'Raster to Other Format' because it gives you a lot more conversion options in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The [Raster to Other Format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000032000000) tool should do what you need.

```
RasterToOtherFormat_conversion (Input_Rasters, Output_Workspace, {Raster_Format})
```