# Arcpy Export Raster Data

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, image-service

**Question**: Is it possible to automate the functionality of right-click layer in TOC > data > export raster using arcpy in ArcGIS Pro? Specifically including the clipping extent options? I have reviewed several similar SE posts ([most relevant here)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107700/export-raster-data-to-tiff-bmp-or-png-file-using-arcpy), but all of them suggest using "copy raster", which does not have the aforementioned clipping options.

**Background**: I'm trying to download data from an image service ([located here](http://moimagery.missouri.edu/arcgis/rest/services/MSDIS/DOQQ2015/ImageServer)). I only want to download subset of the data, similar to a clip or extract by mask (see image below)

[image: aoi]

If I right-click and do data > export raster with the full AOI, i get the following error.

[image]
[image: error]

If I tile up the AOI into much smaller pieces it works perfectly. However, I then face the issues of having to manually right click and extract hundreds of times. I would instead like to automate this with arcpy, but 'export raster'. doesn't seem to be an actual geoprocessing tool.

edit: I've also tried using extract by mask, which works but is far slower. ~5 minutes per 'tile', as opposed to just a few second with when using 'Export Raster'

Comment: Use Copy Raster, set extent in the tool environment settings (or arcpy.env.Extent if scripting)

Comment: Yeah I tried that, for some reason it keeps on the dreaded 999999 error. Extract by mask is working albeit slowly ...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes, the Clip Raster tool does exactly that. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm

Your issue is that you are working with a very large raster from an image service, and running into memory limitations. I think its just going to take a long time. You could try writing the output to memory if its just going to feed into another process.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm

Comment: Can't seem to get that working either - using clip with the image service raster just crashes everything. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- Use [ExtractByMask](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm) instead of Clip Raster
- Before running the extraction, reset your environment extents to limit the scope of what the model is processing.

I have been working with a large raster dataset and the ExtractByMask took several minutes per sub-area before I made this change. Don't forget to reset the environment extents when you are done.

```
# This is the FC that defines the boundary you want to use to extract
extraction_fc 

# Set environment extent temporarily
extraction_extent = arcpy.Describe(extraction_fc).extent
arcpy.env.extent = extraction_extent

# clip raster to extent
out_raster = os.path.join('path','to','output')
outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(in_raster, extraction_fc)
outExtractByMask.save(out_raster)

# reset environment extent
arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"
```